# 手ぇ & つないで meaning and translation help

Tags: translation, compensatory-lengthening

I've been reading よつばと！ and I'm on a chapter where Fuuka has a crush on a guy. She says this:

> 手ぇつないで歩いてたの

I assume the small e is just for emphasis/extension and it doesn't seem to serve a grammatical function (though I'd like to know that for sure), but that's not what poses a problem for me. I have no idea what つないで means. I can't find a definition for it, nor can I for つなぐ, つる, or つある, all of which it is possible inflections of. Can somebody define this for me?

Comment: It is the verb [つなぐ](http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%A4%E3%81%AA%E3%81%90) (in kanji, 繋ぐ). Note: つないで is not a possible inflection of つる (since つる must be a go-dan verb, as must all regular verbs whose dictionary form ends in -uru).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yeah I love よつばと! too. The scene is Fuuka was broken-hearted, right?

The verb `つなぐ`, means "connect", "link", or "join".

In some cases especially in informal scene, post-positional particles like `を` and `に` are omitted.

Example:

```
これから[店]{みせ}へ[行]{い}く。 -> これから店行く。 (I'm gonna go shopping.)

ふーかはあしふといな！ -> ふーかあしふといな！ (Fuuka, your legs are thick!)

だれがうまいことをいえと！ -> だれがうまいこといえと！
(Literally: Who asked you to say that well put thing!)
(Free: That's well put!)
```

As a result, `[手]{て}ぇつないで[歩]{ある}いてたの` can be translated like:

```
[手]{て}ぇつないで[歩]{ある}いてたの = 手をつないで歩いてたの -> He was walking hand in hand (with a girl).
```

Comment: Perhaps "He was walking hand in hand with [someone given in the context of passage]", if not "We were walking hand in hand"?

Comment: @Tim Yes, she saw a guy she likes were walking hand in hand with his girlfriend in the beginning of this episode. She mentioned about that to Yotsuba. BTW If this `手ぇつないで歩いてたの` were read literally, it'll import that she and someone were walking hand in hand.

Answer (score 5):

Not sure what dictionary you are using but according to プログレッシブ英和ー和英中辞典：

> 手をつないで歩く｜walk hand in hand

You tell us this  is spoken so the 手ぇ will be a colloquialism - see comment from Snail plane below - This lengthening applies to other short (monomoraic) words such as 歯 and 目.　（I recently read about this and will add the reference when I find it...)

Comment: Oooh, the を makes it all makes sense if つなぐ means "tied together".

Comment: According to *The Phonology of Japanese* (Labrune 2012, p.52), lengthening sometimes occurs when a particle like を is dropped following a monomoraic word like 手.  So that could explain the `ぇ` after `手`.